# program that does not terminate

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I wrote a program that should take an array of numbers and find the array index of the smallest number. However, when I type the numbers with spaces between and then press enter, the program keeps running. What can be the cause? Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

//read numbers to an array
//find minimum
//print the index of minimum

double findMinimum(int size,double array[]){
int n;
int minIndex=0;
for(n=1;n<size;size++){
    if(array[n]<array[n-1]){
        minIndex=n;
    }
 }
 return minIndex;
}

int main(){
setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);

int size=0;
double inArray[size];

printf("Enter an array of numbers:");

int k=0;
char c;

while(c!='\n'){
  c=getchar();

  if(c=='\n'){
      break;
  }

  scanf("%lf",&inArray[k]);
  k++;
  size++;

  };

 int minIndex=0;
 minIndex=findMinimum(size,inArray);
 printf("The index of minimum number is %i",minIndex);

 return 0;
 }
```

I also took the part of the code that scans numbers to an array. I tried to change the while loop and used "break" statement, but the output gave all numbers in an array except the first one. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

//read numbers to an array

int main(){
setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);

int size=0;
double inArray[size];

printf("Enter an array of numbers ending with question mark:\n");

int k=0;
char c;

while(1){
  c=getchar();

  if(c=='?'){
      break;
  }

  scanf("%lf",&inArray[k]);
  k++;
  size++;
};

int n;
for(n=0;n<size;n++){
    printf("%f\n",inArray[n]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
for(n=1;n<size;size++){
    if(array[n]<array[n-1]){
        minIndex=n;
    }
 }
```

The issue in your code is you are incrementing `size`, thats why your loop is not terminating. increment `n`

**Edit**

you have initialized your 'n' with 1 , however arrays start with zero index thats why it misses the first element,

```
for(n=0;n<size;n++){
    if(array[n]<array[minIndex]){
        minIndex=n;
    }
 }
```

Comment: the condition should be `if(array[n] < array[minIndex])`

Comment: Thank you, now the loop ends. However, the output of the program is wrong. I tried to print the numbers that are stored in the array, and they turned out to be either 0.000000 or random number(garbage). What can be the problem? Is it in the while loop?

Comment: I have tried, but now the program gives the right_index+1. This could be because it does not read the first number in the array. I printed the numbers that are in the inArray and the array lacked first input number.

Comment: @baur arrays start from zero index not 1.

Comment: @OAD: I seem to have accidentally downvoted your answer, and didn't notice my error until it was too late to undo the downvote. (I was viewing the site on mobile and probably touched the downvote button without realizing it.) Would you be kind enough to make some edit (any edit) to your answer? That will unlock my vote so I can correct it. Thanks and apologies!

Comment: @MichaelGeary no problem at all, thats so nice of you that you mentioned what happened otherwise it would not be that much important for anyone else :) and i have edited my answer though ;)

Comment: @OAD: Cool, thanks for editing. Now you have an upvote instead of a downvote! :-) Thanks for your answer, and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
for(n=1; n < size; n++){
    if(array[n]<array[minIndex]){
        minIndex=n;
    }
}
```